# How to Remove the Awkward Margin to the Left of my Unordered List?

Tags: html, css

I have this UnorderedList:

[image]

CSS:

```
.MainMenu
{
    position: absolute;
    top:125px;
    left:15px;    
    background-color: #033E6B;
    color:White;
    border-style:double;
    border-color:White;
}
```

HTML:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainMenu.ascx.cs" Inherits="LoCompro.UserControls.MainMenu" %>
<ul>
    <li>Inico</li>
    <li>Navegar Por Categoria</li>
    <li>Navegar Por Marca</li>
    <li>Buscar</li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it so the List Items dont leave a huge gap on the left? I want it to appears neatly in a box. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul
{
     padding-left:0px;
     margin-left: 0px;
}
```

I suggest using firebug, a FireFox plugin to find these types of issues.  Click element in question, then look at it's "layout."  It'll tell you exactly where padding and margins are coming from.