# Unordered list not aligning all the way to the left in a div

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list that I am using as a simple navigation bar. That looks like below:

[image]

As you can see though that `<li>` elements are not aligning all the way to the left of the `<div>` they are contained in. I have tried `text-align: left;` in the containing `<div>` but that seems to have no effect.

```css
    #menu {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #menu div {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #CACACA;
    }
    
    #menutop {
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    #menutop ul {
        list-style: none;
    }
    
    #menutop li {
       display: inline;
       padding: 10px;
    }
    
    #menutop a {
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #menutop a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="menu">                                                                         
        <div id="menutop">                                                                  
            <ul>                                                                            
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>                                               
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>                                              
            </ul>                                                                           
        </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `margin` of the `ul`?

Comment: Placing your code as is on jsfiddle works as expected. http://jsfiddle.net/5wCZk/. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: You could always use a negative margin: `margin-left: -10px`

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316863/make-the-unordered-list-stick-a-bit-to-the-left

Comment: @Truth: No, your problem lies with jsfiddle. It applies hidden CSS under the hood.

Comment: @PeeHaa Ah I did not see that question when I initially searched. The title of that question is worded strange and this is probably why I did not find it.

Comment: @Eric: Noticed, hence my answer :)

Comment: May be set the divs menu and mennutop to padding: 0 0;

Answer (score 52, accepted):

`ul` and `li` have margin or padding, depending on the browser, by default. You need to override this default style within your menu:

```css
#menu ul, #menu li {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

See a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vg3Wm/)

<sup>Note: By default, jsfiddles does a CSS reset, so is not always well suited for testing this kind of thing. Make sure to disable "Normalized CSS" when looking for this kind of bug.</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize `ul` and `li` elements had padding and margins by default.

Comment: @NicYoung: That's why they appear indented when used as a list. Different browsers achieve the indentation in different ways.

Answer (score 5):

set padding,margin 0px,

```
#menutop ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tQb75/)

http://jsfiddle.net/tQb75/

Answer (score 3):

you can just override ul and li padding and margin.

this simple code:

```
.menu ul, .menu li{
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using a **[CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)**.

The simplest form is:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Not sure resetting everything is the best way to go here. That'll probably break things all over the place.

Comment: @Eric: If resetting breaks your website, **there's your problem!**

Comment: That's somewhat true. There's another issue here though. After you do a reset, you then need to define a basic style for the `ul` to use in an _actual list_. Once again, you have the same problem. You need a margin and padding reset _specific_ to the navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the margin and padding of menu

```
#menu *{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ul>` element is align left, but `<li>` elements have `padding-left` set to `10px`. That's why the first element is slightly to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I created a div with text aligned left and then gave that div margin - x auto. This way the div is centered horizontally.
Any ul inside that div is automatically left aligned and in center.I am using Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="text-left mx-auto"> 
  <ul> 
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an accepted answer already, but for someone out there bootstrap a better way to do this is to throw this for li style

```
text-align: start;
```